# Cross product in curvilinear coordinates in 7D

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, vectors

I am wondering if there exists a formula for cross product of two vectors in seven dimensions in general curvilinear coordinates. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) cross product only makes sense in 3D and [7D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-dimensional_cross_product). For two vectors ($\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$) in three dimensions the formula is:
$\vec{a}\times\vec{b}=\sqrt{\det{g}}\:\varepsilon_{ijk}\:a^i\:b^j\:\vec{e}^k$
where:

$\det{g}$ is determinant of metric tensor

$\varepsilon_{ijk}$ is Levi-Civita symbol

$a^i$ is i-th contravariant component of vector $\vec{a}$

$b^j$ is j-th contravariant component of vector $\vec{b}$

$\vec{e}^k$ is k-th contravariant basis vector

Is there a similar formula for 7D?

Comment: One can define a ["cross product" on $\mathbb{R}^7$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-dimensional_cross_product), but the operation is not invariant under $SO(7)$, so it does not extend to oriented Riemannian manifolds in the same way the three-dimensional product does: Locally, one can choose many inequivalent cross products, but it may not be possible to smoothly glue them together to obtain a global product (and when it is possible, the resulting product is not unique).